# Ghost Submit Button Still in HTML Form Submission

Tags: javascript, forms, events, validation

I have a form that I'm validating with JavaScript before allowing the form to POST.  The validations are done using the LiveValidation library, which I'm having defer doing the validations until the user attempts to submit the form.  So, the Javascript is executing on the form's onsubmit event, returning false if the form is invalid to stop submission.  The form also has multiple submit buttons to determine which action to take with the information on the server's side.  The problem that I'm running into is that if the user clicks on one submit button, fails validation, and then successfully submits again, the first button clicked is also part of the POST, so the action taken on the server's side sometimes isn't the desired one.  I thought that perhaps the problem was with the validation library, but now I'm starting to wonder if it isn't deeper.  If a form's onsubmit returns false, does the set of POSTed variables get cleared or cached for the next submit?

Edit: OK, so this is an instance of the "I'm a dumbass" bug.  I had added a hidden field with this name/value pair through JavaScript earlier, because of some funky business rules on the page.  I just had to remove that, and it's all fine again.

Comment: I'm voting to close the question.

Comment: I think I got it closed, now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to wait for some time to pass before it would let me answer my own question.  Solution reproduced below:

OK, so this is an instance of the "I'm a dumbass" bug. I had added a hidden field with this name/value pair through JavaScript earlier, because of some funky business rules on the page. I just had to remove that, and it's all fine again.